# Where can I find a database of (n,n' gamma) and (n,gamma) reactions sorted by Isotope and Q value

Tags: nuclear-engineering

I have some MCNP spectra with interesting gamma peaks. I can not for the life of me find a database that allows me to search for reactions by Q value or isotope, or both. I can't even find the Q value for Cl-35(n,p) reaction.

I have tried various databases like ENDF and EXFOR, but thus far cannot figure it out! I need to be able to sort by isotope and Q value so I can identify the peaks in the MCNP spectra.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So I found a  database that contains thermal Neutron Capture. I will update this with more information if I find additional useful sources!

https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/capgam/